# Request current user by ID that was returned by login api call

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt

I'm struggling to understand the authentication flow with React/Redux

On login request the API returns the following info about the user:

```
access_token: string
refresh_token: string
id: number
role: string
```

I store that information in my Redux reducer and the tokens get persisted to local storage.

In order to stay signed in after page reload I need to call another API from my root component to get the current user info, but the address of that API depends on the current user ID and role. E.g

```
http://url/${userRole}/${userID}
```

The problem is that after page reload I do not have the ID and the role in my state anymore. Am I supposed to push the ID and the user role to my local storage and query it every time to get the user or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: "The problem is that after page reload I do not have the ID and the role in my state anymore" -> a page reload should not clear the localStorage nor the redux state. Reading variables from redux state (so likely from localStorage) is a common thing. In my apps I store the login token in localStorage and read it for every API calls.

Comment: Page reload does return the Redux state to its initial value unless persisted to the local storage. That's actually my solution to the problem I had. 
I'm not sure if that's a good practice though since all APIs that worked with in the past had a dedicated endpoint that would return a current user by the cookie or token that is attached to that  request and I would calll that endpoint each time on reload to verify the user is still logged in and the access token is valid.

Comment: Ok I see, yes indeed, I've always worked like that and didn't get any issue so far. If you need I can provide you the code to do so.

Comment: I think I figured it out now. Thank you for the insight